# resolving bracketing error when creating constructors in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor, brackets

I am getting a bracketing error in Eclipse (lines 15 & 18) "public Account myCustomAccount ... balance = initial balance; }" when I try to open my second constructor in the following program. The program is for Dietel "Introduction to Programming" chapter 9 exercise 7.

I suspect that I am creating the constructor incorrectly. What advice do you offer? (Thank you kindly in advance!!)

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Account {

//declare required variables
private int id = 0;
private double balance = 0;
private double annualInterestRate = 0; //assume all accounts have the same interest rate
private Date dateCreated = new Date(); //no-argument instance stores the present date


//define default & custom constructors
public Account mydefaultaccount = new Account(); //no-argument instance of Account  

public Account myCustomAccount = new Account(int identNum, double initialBalance) {
    id = identNum;
    balance = initialBalance;
}

//define getters
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public double annualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return dateCreated;
}

//define setters
public void setId(int idSetter) {
    id = idSetter;
}

public void setBalance(double balanceSetter) {
    balance = balanceSetter;
}

public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualSetter) {
    annualInterestRate = annualSetter;
}

//define required monthly interest rate getter
public double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
    double moInt = annualInterestRate / 12;
    return moInt;
}

//define modifiers
public double withdraw(int withdraw) {
    balance = balance - withdraw;
}

public double deposit(int deposit) {
    balance = balance + deposit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't how you define constructors. Constructors should follow the form:

```
public className(parameters) {}
```

Then, to instantiate the class, call this:

```
ClassName variable = new ClassName(Parameters);
```

In your case,

```
public Account() {
    /* Body */
}

public Account(int identNum, double initialBalance) {
    /* Body */
}
```

And to instantiate,

```
Account ac = new Account(Parameters);
```

Comment: thank you very much! i knew something wasn't quite right. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @CameronFarvin If I helped, would appreciate if accepted!

Comment: Apologies, I have now. This was my first SOverflow post.